# Cucumber Table, multiple types of user, multiple types of permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I am trying to make the most efficient use of BDD with Cucumber. Any advice would be appreciated.

I have an app with lots of layers. There are many users from basic admins up to full owners. Each role has different permissions to see different content on their home page. I am guessing the most efficient way to test this is using a table?

Basic user should have just one section on their page, this goes up with each level of user until finally a full owner has possibility of about 20 sections on the page. My initial thoughts are to attempt a table?

For example:

```
Feature: Home Page
  As a user of the app
  I want to see my homepage options
  So I can interact with the correct applications

Background:
  Given I have signed into my account

  Scenario: User can view all their allowed apps
    And my role is '<user>'
    And I navigate to the homepage
    When I click on the available apps opton
    Then I should have '<apps>' available
    Examples:
    | user | apps |
    ...
```

Would I next just write each user out next to each permission they have? Even though the next level up gets the same apps as the previous level?

It just feels like an incredible amount of repetition.

for example:

```
...
Examples:
| user     | apps     |
| level_1  | app_1    |
| level_2  | app_1    |
| level_2  | app_2    |
| level_3  | app_1    |
...
```

Before I even get to level 10 this starts getting silly.

Is there another way to do this? possibly in the steps?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a relatively low level actions in your steps. That doesn't get you any value out of Cucumber.

You can write feature files with a much higher degree of abstraction. For example, using your own words:

```
Scenario: 
  Given there are many users from basic admins up to full owners.
  And each role has different permissions to see different content on their home page.
  When users open their page
  The basic user should have just one section on their page
  And this goes up with each level of user
  And a full owner has possibility of about 20 sections on the page.
```

The trick is that in your step definitions you don't need to check a single user at once.

Comment: OK, thanks that makes it look a lot better for the feature file. I'm still new to Cucumber. My Only other related query is for the business to know that each user is correct[for example user level_4 has the explicit apps(1-4) they are allowed]. Knowing this project these apps will likely change in about 6 months also.
I'm using [level_x] instead of the name of the role and [app_x] instead of the app name.

Comment: You may want to separate testing the behavior of the application from its configuration. This means that you need to describe the behavior of the configuration system instead. To verify the configuration itself, if you write it in json, you can probably just show people and ask them if it is correct.

Comment: ah, good work around, thanks I'll try that.