# How to organize scenarios/feature files with Cucumber

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber, gherkin

I can't find anywhere an example of what is the best logic for scenarios for my case. The application I'm building tests for is a CRM application and a lot of scenarios are repeated many times in one test.

E.g. my first test is to log in to the Admin application, create a text area field and log out. Then I log into the client application and enter the text in the text area field that I created previously and log out. Then I log in again to the Admin application and check if the text I previously typed in the client application is visible and I log out.
The second test is very similar, only instead of a text area I create a gallery, but many scenarios are repeated, such as login and logout.
Each test is in a separate feature file, but it is not easy to read and find something because there are many scenarios that are repeated and they are not small - my login/logout scenarios have 6 steps, some scenarios have more, feature file have more than 1k lines...

Is there a smart way to organize the tests in my case?

Comment: Yikes. It appears Cucumber has been used to automate manual test scripts rather than support BDD.  You would benefit from describing functionality at a much higher level.  Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77431643/cucumber-table-multiple-types-of-user-multiple-types-of-permissions/77433287#77433287 for an example.